# Regular expression to allow specific letters at the end of input text box

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I used below pattern for the text box to allow only the words starting with et and this is working good.

pattern="et.*|ET.*|Et.*

For the same text box I want to add a pattern to allow any word with last letter as 'e' or 't' limiting with only 4 letters.

so it will be like

pattern="et.*|ET.*|Et.*  (or) words ending with letter 'e/E' or t/T with only four letters

I'm new to this, and I tried various things but it is not working.
So, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the pattern I used is  pattern="et.*|ET.*|Et.*

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[etET]{1}$
```

Explanation:

`^` matches start of string

`[a-zA-Z]{3}` allows 3 alphabetical characters

`[etET]{1}` allows 1 character either e, t, E or T

`$` matches end of string

Comment: the last `{1}` shouldn't be required, the `[]` match once by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get words starting by eT too:

```
^([eE][tT].*|.{3}[eEtT])$
```

You may want to change `.` by `[a-zA-Z]` to match only letters.

---

If you don't want words starting by eT

```
^((et|E[tT]).*|.{3}[eEtT])$
```

Comment: Good approach but this will also match `eT`.

Comment: Nice. :) I added a regex in the case you don't want words starting by eT.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex will cover both cases.

```
(^((et)|(Et)|(ET)).*)|(.{3}([eEtT]$))
```

Here, I'm using `^` to specify that the `et` groups should be at the start of the text.

The second case.

`.{3}` means any character 3 times.

`[eEtT]$` either of the characters in the parenthesis and `$` to specify that the text should end with one of these characters.